# Mutiny theme on Ubuntu MATE 14.04

Tags: 14.04, themes, mate

I was using Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS on my notebook, but since Ubuntu 16 (all flavours) are extremely more heavy than older versions, I was thinking about swithing to older versions Ubuntu like 14.04 LTS and more lightweight flavour, I found MATE desktop. I don't like the default layout, but I like [Mutiny](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/02/ubuntu-mate-16-04-unity-style-desktop), because I **love** Unity style.

I found that Mutiny is not available for Ubuntu 14.04, but I don't want to upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04, because let's say that Ubuntu MATE 14.04 consumes about 260MB-300MB RAM and Ubuntu 16.04 consumes about 500MB RAM (double). I rather hate Ubuntu 16.04, and I don't want to switch to LXDE desktop, because I don't like it and there's not a big performance difference between LXDE and MATE.

Is it possible to get Mutiny on Ubuntu MATE 14.04? Mutiny is a panel layout for Ubuntu MATE.

- CPU: Intel Core i3@2.1Ghz
- RAM: 4GB

Comment: You may comment your own question. But you can also easily [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/893037/edit) to clarify your question.

Comment: Ah... well :) the comment was deleted and now your answer is hard to understand without the question. May I still suggest to add the information "Mutiny is a panel layout for Ubuntu MATE" to your question instead of commenting it? You can delete your comment then with the '(x)' button which appears right from the edit link if you get close enough with the mouse.

Comment: Cool. I'm going to delete my comments then.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any definitive info on it but consider that the Mutiny layout/theme was created for the version of the MATE desktop environment that was shipped in Ubuntu 16.04 for the first time. Therefore it likely relies on features that were unavailable before.

It's possible that someone "back-ported" it successfully to an earlier MATE version but I couldn't fin any reference to that.

Please note that Ubuntu MATE 14.04 loses support and becomes off topic here in about a month [as stated in an answer to your forum thread](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/mutiny-on-ubuntu-mate-14-04/11982/4).

Answer (score 0):

[MATE 1.16](https://www.cmscritic.com/ubuntu-mate-16.10-review/) has been packaged for Trusty by [JonathonF](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf). I believe this was the first release with the Mutiny panel arrangement.

To install use these instructions:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/mate-1.16
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mate-desktop
```